# Why does $A_j \subseteq cl ( \bigcup_{m=1}^n A_m )$ imply $cl(A_j) \subseteq cl ( \bigcup_{m=1}^n A_m )$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Why does $A_j \subseteq cl \bigg( \cup_{m=1}^n A_m \bigg)$ imply $cl(A_j) \subseteq cl \bigg( \cup_{m=1}^n A_m \bigg)$?

This is intuitive, but I was thinking of whether one can be sure that there are no counterexamples.

Comment: how do you define closure?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Closure of $K$ is the smallest closed set that contains $K$.

Comment: My problem is with that how can I be sure that $cl(A_j)$ would not have points that could lie outside of the union on the R.H.S. Even if points of $A_j$ are in the union.

Comment: The closure operation is idempotent and (weakly) order preservering so $X\subseteq \operatorname{cl}(Y)$ implies $\operatorname{cl}(X)\subseteq\operatorname{cl}(Y)$ in general.

Answer (score 4):

It's clear that $\operatorname{cl} (\bigcup_{n=1}^m A_m)$ is *a* closed set that contains $A_j$. So the closure of $A_j$, which is the *smallest* closed set containing $A_j$ is a subset of that set. Hence the second inclusion.

Comment: Why does the union being closed imply that the individual closed subset would be there?

Comment: @mavavilj: This is completely independent of what is inside the $\operatorname{cl}(\cdots)$ on the right-hand-side. The point is simply that the entire right-hand side is **one of the things that $\operatorname{cl}(A_j)$ is by definition the smallest of**.

Comment: When one takes $cl(A_j)$ then surely one must add the boundary to $A_j$? Then how does one know that the boundary is in the union?

Comment: @mavavilj: I think you ought to read Henno Brandsma's excellent answer -- instead of just commenting on it without reading what he writes! There is _nothing at all_ about boundaries or unions in this argument.

Comment: If $A_j$ is open, then $cl(A_j) \not= A_j$? Or?

Comment: @mavavilj that’s irrelevant.

Comment: @mavavilj it’s the definition of minimal closed set that you don’t seem to understand.